# Cannot configure QtCreator using CMake on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I am trying to setup a project based on CMake with QtCreator.

In Projects I defined the Build Steps I need.

In the Build setting I get constantly the error message:

> Failed to activate protocol version: "CMAKE_GENERATOR" is set but incompatible with configured generator value

I tried to browse on the Internet for this problem but I could not get rid of this error.

If now I however try to build my project specifying a target, my compile steps are not executed, instead, I get the following message:

> Running "/usr/local/bin/cmake -E server --pipe=/tmp/cmake-W2VOXm/socket --experimental" in xxxx/.Build/release.
>
> CMake Project parsing failed.
>
> Parsing of CMake project failed: Connection to CMake server lost.

Restarting QtCreator does not help, each time the project is opened the message happens again.

Comment: Check CMake generator in your kit options (Tools->Options...->Kits). It should be compatible your build system.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the build directory it's in the same directory than your projects is, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error and have fixed it.

1. Try to reinstall cmake in Ubuntu by follwing https://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/first-step/installation.html#ubuntu.
2. Configurate Tools - Options - build & run regarding "cmake" and "kits". Make sure that one of the configurations (auto-detected or maunal) is corrected.
3. restart qt creator, open project and "run cmake" again.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen and resolved this issue previously by just deleting the build folder, reloading qtcreator and rerunning cmake.